# What is Deposit Insurance for Trading?

Tags: united-states, deposit-insurance, sipc

I was reading a news article for a particular stock and saw an advertisement boldly proclaiming "Lost Your Money?  We will pay you back!"  Suspicious as to what this could possibly mean, I followed the link and found myself on a page offering "Deposit Insurance" with the claim "Insure your deposit and never lose money again".  I thought this was just referring to something similar to SIPC insurance where you are protected in case the broker goes bust, but the listed terms seemed rather wonky.  For instance, you have to apply for this free insurance (why wouldn't it just automatically apply?) and you can select to insure between 10% and 100% of your account balance (why would you ever insure anything less than your full balance?)

Furthermore, there appear to be conditions to getting this insurance, e.g. "Trade the required amount of lots" and furthermore the claim appears to be that you will not lose any money trading, "In case of insured funds loss during trading [we] will compensate them!"  There is even a button to click that says "Try Loss-Free Trading".  This sounds like some kind of purported guarantee that goes beyond not losing funds for non-trading reasons, which I simply can't believe.

The full terms and conditions are not available without logging in to the site, and I'm not interested in doing that without knowing what is going on here; I just want to know exactly what they are claiming.  There is a "customer agreement" that is available, but it makes no mention of this "insurance".  Is this a complete scam?  Is it legitimate, with something in the fine print?

Comment: It's probably a scam.  They ask you for a bunch of personal information to "insure" your deposits, and now they have all of your information.

Comment: Moreover, since most people don't use different email addresses and passwords for different services, they probably get a lot of good usable bank login credentials by forcing victims to make accounts.

Comment: @quid so are you saying they aren't even a legit broker?

Comment: I have no idea because you, rightly, don't name it.  But if I came across anything that claimed to guarantee my account against trading losses and insure my balance with something other than the already available SPIC and FIDC I would assume the whole thing is a scam.  I'd do a whois on the domain and see who is listed as the owner (it's likely private but might be interesting).